# Count number of rows from a specific row number using excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Below is a portion of my script which I use for copying data from my sheet `RawImport` to `PullData`. I have to copy all rows of some single columns from `PullData` worksheet, which contains data starting from row 8.

```
Dim lrA As Integer

lrA = RawImport.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

PullData.Range("A2:A" & lrA).Value = RawImport.Range("G8:G" & lrA).Value
PullData.Range("A2:A" & lrA).NumberFormat = "d mmm yyyy h:mm;@"
PullData.Range("A:A").Columns.AutoFit

PullData.Range("B2:B" & lrA).Value = RawImport.Range("E8:E" & lrA).Value
PullData.Range("C2:C" & lrA).Value = RawImport.Range("C8:C" & lrA).Value
PullData.Range("D2:D" & lrA).Value = RawImport.Range("D8:E" & lrA).Value
PullData.Range("E2:E" & lrA).Value = RawImport.Range("B8:B" & lrA).Value
PullData.Range("F2:F" & lrA).Value = RawImport.Range("F8:F" & lrA).Value
```

The problem I face with above code is that it's including data from the first 8 rows as well. Thus the script is copying some values as `N/A` in the remaining rows at the end.

I tried to edit the line which counts the rows as follows:

```
 lrA = RawImport.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 7
```

But this removed 7 rows from the bottom of the range that contained data, instead of first 7.

How can insert data from row 8?

Comment: @Mrig:         That is writing data from B8 column in my destination sheet PullData

Comment: Are you copying data from sheet RawImport to PullData or vice versa?

Comment: I figured it myself. changing all the line to lrA + 7 did the trick. Ex: PullData.Range("B2:B" & lrA).Value = RawImport.Range("E8:E" & lrA + 7).Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the code like this:

```
Dim lrA As Integer

lrA = RawImport.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

PullData.Range("A2:A" & lrA - 6).Value = RawImport.Range("G8:G" & lrA).Value
PullData.Range("A2:A" & lrA - 6).NumberFormat = "d mmm yyyy h:mm;@"
PullData.Range("A:A").Columns.AutoFit

PullData.Range("B2:B" & lrA - 6).Value = RawImport.Range("E8:E" & lrA).Value

PullData.Range("C2:C" & lrA - 6).Value = RawImport.Range("C8:C" & lrA).Value

PullData.Range("D2:D" & lrA - 6).Value = RawImport.Range("D8:E" & lrA).Value

PullData.Range("E2:E" & lrA - 6).Value = RawImport.Range("B8:B" & lrA).Value

PullData.Range("F2:F" & lrA - 6).Value = RawImport.Range("F8:F" & lrA).Value
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you didn't specify the **starting point** of your range. Since you have to *copy* all rows, (I'm assuming you can copy-paste everything, not just the values) just use the following:

```
RawImport.Rows("8:" & lra).Copy Destination:=PullData.Range("A2")
```

This will copy all the rows from the 8th to the `lra`th in the `PullData` Worksheet, starting from range "A2", exactly like you copy-pasted with CTRL+C / CTRL+V

EDIT:

Ok I think I got what you were thinking (and edited your question accordingly). You *can* use `.Copy` anyway:

```
RawImport.Range(Cells(8, x).Address(0, 0), Cells(lra, x).Address(0, 0)).Copy _
Destination:=PullData.Range("A2") 'or whatever range you need
```

where `x` is in this case the column you wanted to select in your source worksheet.

Comment: I am using the columns on my destination sheet in different order than my source sheet, So I don't want to use copy method

Comment: Could you please edit the question and explain exactly *what* you want to copy? Do you just want to copy a single column? From row 8 to row lra?

Comment: I figured it out now. changing all the line  to lrA + 7 did the trick. PullData.Range("B2:B" & lrA).Value = RawImport.Range("E8:E" & lrA + 7).Value

Comment: It's ok as well. However, with `.Copy` you are allowed to use only the starting point of the range, without having to think about how many rows are in the copied one

Answer (score 0):

Your ranges differ, try subtracting `6` from `lrA` on the left-hand-side. Apply the change to all lines, where you copy data:

```
PullData.Range("A2:A" & lrA - 6).Value = RawImport.Range("G8:G" & lrA).Value
```

Also, I think this is unwanted:

```
PullData.Range("D2:D" & lrA).Value = RawImport.Range("D8:E" & lrA).Value
```

You copy columns `D` and `E` from `RawImport` into `D` in `PullData`.